# Using javascript take a screenshot of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, screenshot

```js
var takeScreenShot = function(){
 html2canvas(document.body, {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
   var tempcanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
            tempcanvas.width=1350;
            tempcanvas.height=1350;
            var context=tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(canvas,112,0,288,200,0,0,350,350);
            var link=document.createElement("a");
            link.href=tempcanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');   //function blocks CORS
            link.download = 'screenshot.jpg';
            link.click();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="container">
   <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
   <button onclick="takeScreenShot()">Snapshot</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to take a screenshot of bootstrap modal and save it as image file. I'm using html2canvas library. When snapshot button clicks but i want convert modal into image.

Anyone have solution for this..

Comment: This is not enough detail. Can you please include any code that you have.

Comment: As I understood, you need to pass modal wrap element to `html2canvas()`

Comment: I passed modal id it's working now thank you..

Answer (score 3):

Try this !!

```
html2canvas($("#modelId"), {
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "Project.png");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i have image in modal, that image is not displayed in screenshot. Solution plz.